# QSqlQuery ignoring sort order for SQLite DB

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

The results returned by my `QSqlQuery` are always in the same order, regardless of the `ORDER BY` state:

```
void Sy_loggingModel::reload()
{
    auto query = d_->buildQuery();
    query.setForwardOnly( true );
    if ( !query.exec() ) {
        throw Sy_exception( QObject::tr( "Failed to query logging data: " ) +
                            query.lastError().text() );
    }

    beginResetModel();

    qDebug() << query.lastQuery()
             << d_->filter_        // First ? param
             << d_->sortedColumn_; // Second ? param

    d_->entries_.clear();
    while ( query.next() ) {
        auto timestamp = query.value( 1 ).toLongLong();
        auto level = query.value( 2 ).toInt();

        d_->entries_ << Sy_loggingModel_d::Entry{
                            query.value( 0 ).toLongLong(),
                            QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch( timestamp ).toString(),
                            static_cast< Sy_loggerInterface::DebugLevel >( level ),
                            query.value( 3 ).toString() };

        qDebug() << "\t" << query.value( 0 ).toLongLong()
                         << timestamp
                         << level
                         << query.value( 3 ).toString();
    }

    endResetModel();
}
```

Produces this output when alternating between sort orders:

```
"SELECT rowid, timestamp, debugLevel, message FROM Sy_logger WHERE rowid >= ? AND debugLevel IN ( 0, 1, 2 ) ORDER BY ? DESC;" 0 1
     1 1415399097350 0 "Opened database ./logs/Syren2.log"
     2 1415399097382 1 "Listening on port 23000"
     3 1415399418377 2 "New log rotation settings received, Metric: 0, Interval: 720"
     4 1416178611851 2 "Opened database ./logs/Syren2.log"
     5 1416178611852 2 "Listening on port 23000"
     6 1416178612776 2 "New log rotation settings received, Metric: 0, Interval: 720"


"SELECT rowid, timestamp, debugLevel, message FROM Sy_logger WHERE rowid >= ? AND debugLevel IN ( 0, 1, 2 ) ORDER BY ? ASC;" 0 1
     1 1415399097350 0 "Opened database ./logs/Syren2.log"
     2 1415399097382 1 "Listening on port 23000"
     3 1415399418377 2 "New log rotation settings received, Metric: 0, Interval: 720"
     4 1416178611851 2 "Opened database ./logs/Syren2.log"
     5 1416178611852 2 "Listening on port 23000"
     6 1416178612776 2 "New log rotation settings received, Metric: 0, Interval: 720"
```

The SQL statement returns the expected result set when used from the command line.  Any suggestions?  I'm using Qt v5.3.2.

Comment: It looks like you're using a prepared query, but your example code doesn't include the part where the query is built.

Comment: @MrEricSir You are right, I didn't feel it necessary to show the code as I give it's output as returned by `QSqlQuery::lastQuery()` - which is the important bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby) says:

> If the ORDER BY expression is a constant integer K then the expression is considered an alias for the K-th column of the result set.

However, parameters are not considered constants, so the value you use for this parameters is used as an expression that happens to be the same for all rows.

If you want to sort by different columns, you have to construct the SQL statement dynamically.